# pass php variable to select the right option

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the option based on the php variable value. So I need `option value=1` is selected in the first `<select>` and `option value=6` selected in second . Since I have a bunch of other `<select>` in the form, eventually, I will have an php array of some values, and I need each of the value match up with the option value under corresponding index in the a group of `<select>` that sharing the same `class='si_1'`, and assign `selected` to that option.

Thanks

php part

```
<?php 
$select_1 = "1";
$select_2 = "6";
?>
```

JQuery part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sel_class = $(".si_1");
    var array = {"<?php echo $select_1?>","<?php echo $select_2?>"};
    JQuery.each(array, function(index, value) {
        var current = sel_class.get(index);
        $(current + " option[value=" + value + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

I don't know if `$(current + " option[value=" + value + "]")` is the correct syntax to target the `<select>` at `index in $(".si_1")` that has `option` where the `option attribute value` has value that's at `index in array`

HTML part

```
<select class="si_1">
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="5">Test 5</option>
    <option value="7">Test 7</option>
</select>
<select class="si_1">
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="6">Test 6</option>
    <option value="8">Test 8</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the JavaScript:

```
selectedVal1 = "<?= $select_1; ?>";
selectedVal2 = "<?= $select_2; ?>";
```

When the client looks at it, it will look like this:

```
selectedVal1 = "1";
selectedVal2 = "6";
```

Then it's just using jQuery to set the `selected` attribute to `selected` (Just do .attr('selected', 'selected'))

Comment: The `<?= .. ?>` tags are just a neater way of writing `<? echo .. ?>` in most cases (There may be exceptions), in-case you weren't aware.

Comment: could you take a look at my code again because I accidentally put up the wrong code. I kinda need everything in an array, so I can loop through them. Yea, I'm aware that `<?= ..?>` is another way to write `echo`, it's just that there seems something that the php 5.3 on my wamp server doesn't support that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, could you post what the JavaScript looks like on the page?